# Eureka Forms Multiple Selector Row set default values

Tags: swift3, eureka-forms

I have a Swift 3 app where I am using Eureka Forms.

Within the form to create an object I am using the MultipleSelectorRow, which works well.

However, how do I set the default values for this?

If I use the following code I get an error stating "Cannot assign value of type [String] to type Set[String]"

```
<<< MultipleSelectorRow<String>() {
  $0.tag = "gradeType"
  $0.title = "Grade Types"
  $0.selectorTitle = "Pick the posted grade types"
  $0.value = prevGradeTypeList
  $0.options = gradeTypePicker
}
```

Comment: Can you share your vars definitions for  `prevGradeTypeList` and `gradeTypePicker`?

Answer (score 1):

In Eureka, "value" in MultipleSelectorRow is a Set. You'll need to convert your array to a set before assigning it.

There are a couple of differences between a Set and an Array in Swift you should be aware of:

1) Values in a Set are unordered (they won't appear in the same order as in your original Array)

2) Values in a Set are unique (duplicate items from your Array will only appear as one value)

3) Values must be hashable. All the basic types in Swift, including String, will work. (Also: Int, Double, Bool)

Just convert your Array to a Set before assigning it to Value:

```
$0.value = Set(prevGradeTypeList)
```